# html5 css3 show image for svg hover

Tags: html, css, svg

I have following markup for svg in html5 css 3

```
<svg id="optionSvg" width="88" height="178">
    <rect id="opt1" class="mouseOver item1" x="125" y="70" width="200" height="150" fill="blue" stroke="black" style="z-index: 1"></rect>
    <rect id="opt2" class="mouseOver" x="350" y="70" width="200" height="150" fill="yellow" stroke="black"></rect>
    <rect id="opt3" class="mouseOver" x="125" y="250" width="200" height="150" fill="green" stroke="black"></rect>
    <rect id="opt4" class="mouseOver" x="350" y="250" width="200" height="150" fill="orange" stroke="black"></rect>
    <rect id="opt5" class="mouseOver" x="125" y="430" width="430" height="150" fill="purple" stroke="black"></rect>
</svg>
```

And here is the css class

```
    .mouseOver:hover {
        opacity: 0.1;
        fill: white;
        z-index: -1;
        position: relative;
    }

    .item1:hover {
        position: relative;
        background: url(testImage.png) no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        animation: ease-in;
    }
```

So what I want to do is to show testImage.png when the mouse is hovered on the first  item, but looks like its not working. **no jQuery please, javascript OK**

Comment: It's not working because you are writing your style declarations as if they were HTML. There's no `position`, `z-index`, `background`, `background-attachment`, `animation` attributes in SVG. This needs a complete rewrite.

Comment: svg does fade out I want to figure our how can I show images beneath to that. If flexbox can do the job, please feel free to share the code.